# Can not find the class in scope in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am usin swiftUI . I have one view name **MyView**. I want to call **LoginViewModel** class  method which is in the another folder. When I try to call the class, it shows Cannot find 'LoginViewModel' in scope. But when I declare the class in MyView class, it is working fine.

Here is the image of MyView:

[image]

Here is the code LoginViewModel class code which is in **view_model** folder.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
 class LoginViewModel {
     func doLogin(`var` parameters: [String: Any]){
       ...
    }
 }
```

What is the wrong with this?

Comment: Did you include `LoginViewModel.swift` in the same target as `MyView`?

Comment: @Asperi No. I did not incloude

Comment: Then you have to. :)

Answer (score 5):

grate ! you put you your class to another folder, I am sure the folder is not in same target where your `MyView` in .

include `LoginViewModel.swift` to same target as `MyView` or make a class on same folder .